# VB.NET: How to convert from a string to method name?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have my method name as a string(Eventually going to read from a file). For now the method can be accessed by AIModule.Main, then it is going to be run as a different thread. So far I have this:

```
Dim MyMethod As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = Me.GetType().GetMethod("AIModule.Main")
AIThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf MyMethod)
```

But this doesn't work, as the AddressOf operator only wants names. How would I make it such that I get the method name or indeed the method address?

Thank you.

Comment: You might explore creating a ThreadStart delegate as described by Jon Skeet in a similar discussion I've linked herein. Although that discussion is C# based, I believe the concepts can be translated to VB.NET.  https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/118191-using-reflection-multithreading

Comment: You have to call MyMethod.Invoke().  Most easily done with a lambda expression: `New Thread(Sub() MyMethod.Invoke(Me, Nothing))`.  If the method is Shared then pass Nothing instead of Me.

Comment: Might the new VS 2015 NameOf() operator be useful?

Answer (score 0):

With the full-disclosure up front that this is taken from a post Jon Skeet offered in response to a similar question in a different forum, his proposed solution to this issue would be to create a ThreadStart delegate in a manner like this (C# source here):

```
ThreadStart ts = (ThreadStart) Delegate.CreateDelegate
 (typeof (ThreadStart), methodInfo);
```

A rough VB adaptation from your source might look like (warning - untested! - offered for illustration):

```
Dim MyThreadStart as ThreadStart = Delegate.CreateDelegate(GetType(ThreadStart), MyMethod) as ThreadStart
```

It would seem you have these basic pieces in hand and could adapt that solution accordingly.

[Original thread with Jon Skeet's discussion here](https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/118191-using-reflection-multithreading)